# Pass to generic function argument which type is a key of the generic AND object[key] is number

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a generic function:

```
function mkSorter<T extends { [key: string]: unknown }, K extends keyof T>(prop: K) {
  return (a: T, b: T) => a[prop] - b[prop];
}
```

How can I set another constraint for the property value to be number, so that `prop: keyof T` and `T[K]: number`?

**UPDATE:**

In order to use it this way:

```
type SomeObjectType = {
  number: number;
  alsoNumber: number;
  string: string;
  anotherString: string;
  bool: boolean;
};

const columns: ColumnsType<SomeObjectType> = [
  {
    title: 'Also number',
    dataIndex: 'alsoNumber',
    render: renderColumnWNumber,
    sorter: mkSorter<SomeObjectType>('alsoNumber'),
    defaultSortOrder: 'descend',
  },
];
```

So as to it wouldn't be possible to pass anything except for `'number'` and `'alsoNumber'` values.

[Invalid playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwNYGU4CcoFMsA8AKorgB55gAmAzogN6IDaquAngFyI1RYxgBzALpdwqMHADuSAL4A%20ABQAHLHCVdWbOMEREAlAwBQiRFlxQQWJAoCGXIgBpEAI3sGAvHMQ2mKtUMQAWhdfVSUhAG5DGUNDKDYlXERMZFwAeWcAK1xoIgSk9yMTMBBkZ3wuErL8KJMbABsaOAA5UvKsSraa425efgEuHj5BWu8JKAALfHQ%20wUHZgVHnODh6rmXV3BswKJkowwgEHkRD%20tKwGi4AYVXzmjzEghT0rJyoB9wvQqYe%20h6TWBQeq4LgAcgAgo04Igqu1QQ5-ogqDYoDYAJLUchghpNVrVLDwxFNHAVFAYbB4QjPDLZXL5RSgnEtLoEvQIkwmKi4YA2ED1KCYHBpLBcjqIUFcmgQXDUQkmGQIyJAA)

**ANOTHER UPDATE:**

People gave me [this option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#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-f8oFK-bh0EUTYMDCrzkA) (It works! Unfortunately, autocomplete doesn't):

```
type NumericKeys<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends number ? P : never }[keyof T]
type NumericFields<T> = { [P in NumericKeys<T>]: number }

function mkSorter<T, N extends NumericFields<T> = NumericFields<T>>(prop: keyof N) {
  return (a: T & N, b: T & N) => a[prop] - b[prop];
}
```

Comment: If `sorter` in `ColumnsType<T>` is typed as `(a: T, b: T) => number` then there's a solution that doesn't require the explicit type parameter (so you can write `mkSorter('number')` instead of `mkSorter<SomeObjectType>('number')`). In case you're still interested I can update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since only the result of `mkSorter` is generic with respect to `T`, you can also move that generic parameter inside and use a helper type to enforce the presence of the `number` property on the `a` and `b` arguments:

```
type WithNumber<T, K extends PropertyKey> = T & {[_ in K]: number} 

function mkSorter<K extends string>(prop: K) {
  return <T,>(a: WithNumber<T,K>, b: WithNumber<T,K>) => a[prop] - b[prop]
}
```

This is slightly different from your original approach in that created sorters will be generic, so you can apply them to different object types (as long as these have the appropriate `number` property):

```
const sorter = mkSorter('k')
const test1 = sorter({k: 9, a: true}, {k: 9, a: false})
const test2 = sorter({k: 9, b: true}, {k: 9, b: false})
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgOQK4FsBGEBOAeAFQBooBpKCAD2AgDsATAZygAUcB7SHUUiEAPigBeKASgAyKAG8A2gH0ocWmQC6ALii0M2HAF8oAKAMAzVLQDGwOO2XoA1gGV23XHnJUaDZo2A4lAc34ACjAOMA1SAEppAygoHAhgVBxlQiJggEMNeCQ0LFdiUn4STGyEFG0CoiLooUEMmVDOFSgAWihMRrCVA10jcxsfKEZnGhxhKHsnFxwggHI7OciDAdohmh8ARgmRmaCpOw0AThIsqF9UCF0SA%20PTjWMMgBtGK%20XV9YgfACYd0dx9ocoCcOhoLlcbkCQaUoI8Xm8DEA)

Comment: Elegant solution!

Comment: Thanks, captain!

Comment: Wow, I every time learning smth new from you. I will remove my answer

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Maybe, I was ambiguous, so I updated the post with a usage example I try to implement.

Comment: Ah, I see, in that case the generic parameter should be on the outside. How do you type `sorter` in your `ColumnsType<T>`? If it's `(a: T, b: T) => number` I can tweak the solution.